# change order of lines position in json file

Tags: sed, json, jq

#### i want the row of `description` to be after row of `body`

EXAMPLE.

### from:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "prefix": "foo",
        "description": "foo",
        "body": [
            "line 1",
            "  line 2"
        ]
    },
    "bar": {
        "prefix": "bar1",
        "description": "bar 1 bar",
        "body": [
            "line 1",
            "  line 2",
            "  line 3",
            "...."
        ]
    }
}
```

### TO:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "prefix": "foo",
        "body": [
            "line 1",
            "  line 2"
        ],
        "description": "foo"
    },
    "bar": {
        "prefix": "bar1",
        "body": [
            "line 1",
            "  line 2",
            "  line 3",
            "...."
        ],
        "description": "bar 1 bar"
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is your question? and how does that relate to the topic of this website?

Comment: Why would you want this? Most applications of json shouldn’t care about the order of the keys. If you really need this, install the `jq` tool, which is far more suited to json manipulation than sed, awk and echo. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ (also available in most modern distros)

Comment: luasnip for neovim need order to work

Comment: I don't think you should worry about that. It's like having an object. Do you care about the order of the object properties?

Comment: The input data has changed to what the output data should be? I have provided an answer that now seems redundant. Should it be deleted to match with the changing request?

Comment: sed work for me now for "foo/bar" but still not universe "foo 1 foo"... but i can fixit

Comment: @hatless understand me and write `sed` command work for this situation but not universe , i try to fix .[a-z]. to be universe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your first JSON document is what you have, and that your second JSON document shows what you want to get.

Using `jq`:

```bsh
jq '.[] |= ( to_entries | [.[0],.[2],.[1]] | from_entries )' file
```

The first bit, `to_entries`, is applied to each each of two sub-objects `foo` and `bar`, and it turns these into "entries", i.e. arrays with `key` and `value` keys.  The `foo` object turns, for example, into

```json
[
  {
    "key": "prefix",
    "value": "foo"
  },
  {
    "key": "description",
    "value": "foo"
  },
  {
    "key": "body",
    "value": [
      "line 1",
      "  line 2"
    ]
  }
]
```

Here, we just need to rearrange the three element in the array from the order 0, 1, 2 into the order 0, 2, 1,  i.e. we need to swap the last to entries.

This is what we do with `[.[0],.[2],.[1]]`.

We then turn the array back to an ordinary object with `from_entries`.

Testing this on your data returns

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "prefix": "foo",
    "body": [
      "line 1",
      "  line 2"
    ],
    "description": "foo"
  },
  "bar": {
    "prefix": "bar1",
    "body": [
      "line 1",
      "  line 2",
      "  line 3",
      "...."
    ],
    "description": "bar 1 bar"
  }
}
```

---

If you are happy with naming the keys (instead of just swapping the last two keys) in each sub-object, the following will have the same effect as the command above:

```bsh
jq '.[] |= { prefix: .prefix, body: .body, description: .description }' file
```

This basically creates a *new* object for each of the two sub-objects `foo` and `bar`, with the keys in the specified order.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
sed '/description/d; s/.prefix.:\s\(.[a-z]*.\)./&\n\t"description": \1/' $file
```

This solution will delete all lines containing the string `description`.

After which it will match all lines matching `prefix` and substitute it back with itself with `&` then movee to the new line.

`description` is then manually inserted with the `foo` or `bar` grouped `()` from the previous match and backslashed back in `\1`

```
{
    "foo": {
        "prefix": "foo",
        "description": "foo"
        "body": [
            "line 1",
            "  line 2",
        ],
    },
    "bar": {
        "prefix": "bar",
        "description": "bar"
        "body": [
            "line 1",
            "  line 2",
            "  line 3",
            "...."
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: it's work because `foo` is one work and description is one word ...

Comment: @AyoubElMhamdi That is great. Please fix your question. Your input and output are now the same.

Comment: That output isn't valid JSON as it has a comma after each `]` and no comma at the end of the "description" line. Try piping it to `jq .` to validate it. Actually, that approach can't work at all since it's deleting the description lines and then creating new ones from the prefix lines rather than moving the description lines and so the content will be changed.

Comment: .[a-z]*. must to be universe

Comment: @EdMorton Indeed. The only thing preserved will be `foo` or `bar`. I guess it would depend on use case. I doubt it is valid JSON either but worked from input available at the time which has now changed. `awk` would be a better tool.

Comment: @AyoubElMhamdi `[a-z]*` will match letters a-z followed by a single character, in this case `"`.

Comment: change .[a-z]*.to be ..[0-9a-z]*..  and line that remove must be restore

Comment: i tank easy to do that with sed  or jq

Comment: The problem is that when printing the new description line after prefix you need to know the contents of the original description line that's a varying number of lines below it. You'd have to completely scrap your solution and, if you wanted to stick with sed, come up with a new one involving reading the lines between prefix and description into a hold space then swap them or using GNU sed for -z and use a global regexp sub across the whole input or something. It'd be a convoluted, probably nonportable, mess that'd be vastly simpler if done with awk if you want to use mandatory Unix tool.

Comment: so i can not restore line content `"description"` , if we use group , \1 \2 , i think , we can restore it

Comment: @EdMorton Agreed. awk or jq (if valid JSON) would be the appropriate tool.

Comment: @AyoubElMhamdi correct, you cannot restore it with the approach of the sed script in this answer, you'd need a completely different sed (or some other tool) script as described in my comment above.

Comment: @AyoubElMhamdi No. It was deleted in the first step and manually reinserted. You will need a new script to implement a constant `description`.  You cannot use \2 because it was not created.